# First flutter app. Trying to call a method from widget home screen

Tags: flutter

I took an application from the internet using flutter_google_maps plugin. To this I added a method called centermap. I have tried countless things to try and get the app to read centermap and relocate the google map to the coordinates. I have tried googling but can't find any examples of doing this in Flutter.

Can some help to get me going. In the orginal code I copied the raised button works.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

GoogleMapController mapController;

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Google Maps demo')),
      body: MapsDemo(),
    ),
  ));

  centerMap(mapController);
}

class MapsDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => MapsDemoState();

}

class MapsDemoState extends State<MapsDemo> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding (
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 400.0,
              height: 500.0,
              child: GoogleMap(
                onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
              ),

            ),
          ),
          RaisedButton(
              child: const Text('Go to London'),
              onPressed: mapController ==  null ? null : (){
                mapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
                  const CameraPosition(
                    bearing: 270.0,
                    target: LatLng(51.5160895, -0.1294527),
                    tilt: 30.0,
                    zoom: 17.0,
                  ),
                ));
              },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    setState(() {
      mapController = controller;
    });
  }
}

void centerMap(GoogleMapController mapController) {
  mapController.animateCamera(
    CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
      CameraPosition(
          target: LatLng(37.4219999, -122.0862462), zoom: 20.0),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I should have kept trying a few more minutes

This seems to work

```
void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    setState(() {
      mapController = controller;
    });
    centerMap(mapController);
  }
}

void centerMap(GoogleMapController mapController) {
  mapController.animateCamera(
    CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
      CameraPosition(
          target: LatLng(37.4219999, -122.0862462), zoom: 20.0),
    ),
  );
}
```